# Extracting CD tagged tokens using UIMA

Tags: uima

I wrote an annotator that extracts all CD tagged tokens and the code looks like this

```
public class WeightAnnotator extends JCasAnnotator_ImplBase {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
public static List<Token> weightTokens = new ArrayList<Token>();

public static final String PARAM_STRING = "stringParam";
@ConfigurationParameter(name = PARAM_STRING)
private String stringParam;

@Override
public void initialize(UimaContext context) throws ResourceInitializationException {
    super.initialize(context);
}


@Override
public void process(JCas jCas) throws AnalysisEngineProcessException {
    logger.info("Starting processing.");

    for (Sentence sentence : JCasUtil.select(jCas, Sentence.class)) {

    List<Token> tokens = JCasUtil.selectCovered(jCas, Token.class, sentence);
        for (Token token : tokens) {
             int begin = token.getBegin();
             int end = token.getEnd();
            if (token.getPos().equals( PARAM_STRING)) {
                WeightAnnotation ann = new WeightAnnotation(jCas, begin, end);
                ann.addToIndexes();
                System.out.println("Token: " + token.getCoveredText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

but when I am trying to create an iterator on it in a pipeline, the iterator is returning null. Here is how my pipeline looks.

```
            AnalysisEngineDescription weightDescriptor = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(WeightAnnotator.class,
            WeightAnnotator.PARAM_STRING, "CD"
            );

    AggregateBuilder builder = new AggregateBuilder();
    builder.add(sentenceDetectorDescription);
    builder.add(tokenDescriptor);
    builder.add(posDescriptor);
    builder.add(weightDescriptor);
    builder.add(writer);

    for (JCas jcas : SimplePipeline.iteratePipeline(reader, builder.createAggregateDescription())) {

       Iterator iterator1 = JCasUtil.iterator(jcas, WeightAnnotation.class);

        while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
            WeightAnnotation weights = (WeightAnnotation) iterator1.next();
            logger.info("Token: " + weights.getCoveredText());
        }
    }
```

I generated WeightAnnotator and WeightAnnotator_Type using JCasGen. I debugged the entire code but I don't understand where I am getting this wrong. Any ideas on how to improve this are appreciated.

Comment: The information you provide is not sufficient. E.g. we do not know what the return type of token.getPos() is. In any case, you would have to compare against "paramString", not "PARAM_STRING", because the parameter value is injected into the variable "paramString" whereas "PARAM_STRING" is a constant representing the parameter name. It also seems that your analysis engine and your annotation type are both called "WeightAnnotator". Call the AE "WeightAnnotator" and the type "WeightAnnotation". Annotations should be added to the CAS, not be stored in a static variable inside your annotator.

Comment: @rec: token.getPos() returns POS tag of that token. Here I am looking for only one type POS tag "CD" so I compared with "PARAM_STRING". And I will make changes to the type name as you suggested. And I think adding annotations to the CAS is where I am confused. I wrote a CasConsumer class for it but it is throwing 'trying to serialize non xml character' exception. I will add it to my original post if you want me to. But a small example on how to add annotations to CAS should be keep me going. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you have created a type called "WeightAnnotation", you would create and add it to the CAS using "WeightAnnotation anno = new WeightAnnotation(jcas, begin, end); anno.addToIndexes();" If WeightAnnotation has any features, you should set them before calling addToIndexes(). If you make changes, please also update your code above to reflect the new state.

Comment: @rec: Thanks for response. I made changes as you suggested, but the logger I used in the pipeline doesn't log anything. The code above reflects the changes that I made.

Comment: @rec: That actually worked, thanks for your input. Could you also tell what is the better to serialize CAS and collect output from pipeline into a file?

Comment: If you want to write to a file, write yourself a CAS Consumer (basically an AE which does not add annotations to the CAS, but which writes them to a file or elsewhere instead). If you want want to embed your pipeline in an application and wish to use the information from the CAS directly, the approach using the for loop (as you have) is nice. However, mind that you cannot keep a hold on annotation objects and use them outside the loop, because the CAS is reset and reused in every iteration which invalidates the annotation that you hold on to.

Comment: @rec: I posted my CAS consumer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416008/cas-consumer-not-working-as-expected), please look at it and correct me where I am getting it wrong. Thanks.